# frequency of desired characters in the given string

Tags: python

Can anyone help me with the Python code to return the most frequently occurring characters and their respective counts in a given string?

For example, `"aaaaabbbbccc", 2` should return `[('a', 5), ('b', 4)]`

In case of a tie, the character which comes later in alphabet comes first
in the ordering.  For example:

```
 "cdbba",2 -> [('b',2), ('d',1)]
 'cdbba',3 -> [('b',2), ('d',1), ('c',1)]
```

Comment: Try using a dictionary

Comment: Better, use `collections.Counter`

Comment: In the example `"aaaaabbbbccc", 2`, what is the significance of the `2`?  Is it the first 2 in the alphabet, or the first two occurring in the string?

Comment: @cdarke: The top two most frequent.

Comment: No offence, but I'm trying, and its not my home work

Comment: 2 is the top most frequent characters

Comment: Which version of Python?  I ask because `sort` functions are slightly different between 2 and 3 (specifically `cmp`).

Comment: This question is not a duplicated, the OP wants a different output. The order is not the same as the "original duplicated questions"

Answer (score 0):

This could be a start for you:

```
 from collections import Counter
 import string
 s = "aaaaabbbbccc"
 counter = Counter(s)

 for c in string.ascii_letters:
     if counter[c] > 0:
          print (c, counter[c])
```

You can adjust the code, and instead of printing, save the results in a list, sort it, and print top 2 results

Answer (score 0):

First of all - **What have you tried so far?**
Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking!

To solve that, first create a dictionary of frequencies, after that convert it to an array of tuples, and lastly sort.

```
def freq(st, n):
    # Create the dictionary
    dct = {}
    for c in st:
        dct[c] = dct.get(c, 0) + 1
    # Convert to array of tuples
    ar = [(key, val) for key, val in dct.iteritems()]
    # Sort the array:
    ar.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

    return ar[:n]
```

This will not solve your question completely - you still need to figure out how to break the ties. Here is one way: create another dictionary of first occurrences (just a dict with character as the key, and index as value), and before returning check iterate again while identifying the ties, and resolving them.

Answer (score 0):

```
def freq(word, n):
    l1 = list(word)
    l3 = []
    l2 = []
    l4 = []
    s = set(l1)
    l2 = list(s)

    def count(p):
        c = 0
        for a in word:
            if a in word:
                c = c + p.count(a)
        l3.append(c)
        return c

    l2.sort(key=count)

    l3.sort()
    l4 = list(zip(l2, l3))
    l4.reverse()
    l4.sort(key=lambda l4: ((l4[1]), (l4[0])), reverse=True)
    return l4[0:n]
    pass
```

Comment: I got answer with this code

Answer (score 0):

def freq(word, n):
    res=[]
    a = []
    b = []
    c=0

```
if type(word) != str or type(n) != int:
    c = 1
    raise TypeError
if n <= 0:
    c = 1
    raise ValueError
for x in word:
    a.append(x)
    b.append(word.count(x))
c = zip(a, b)
c = list(set(c))
c.sort(key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=True)

c.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
count=0
for x in range(len(c)):
    count+=1
if n>count:
    n=count
for x in range(n):
    res.append(c[x],)
return res
```

Comment: This code also solves

Answer (score -1):

`Counter` built-in class provides a function called `most_common`.

> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the
>   most common to the least. If n is omitted or None, most_common()
>   returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are
>   ordered arbitrarily:

After getting characters and their frequency, we need to sort them first for his frequency and if there is a tie, we select the character with the highest ascii code. Then, we just pick up the N most common elements slicing by any number.

```
from collections import Counter

s = "cdbba"
sorted_counter = sorted(Counter(s).most_common(), 
                        key = lambda x: (-x[1], -ord(x[0])))
slice_counter = sorted_counter[:2] # here you select n most common
>[('b',2), ('d',1)]
slice_counter = sorted_counter[:3] # here you select n most common
>[('b',2), ('d',1), ('c',1)]
```

Comment: why the downvote? this gives the correct answer.